# Load the referenced table of a referenced table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core

I have multiple tables that refer to other tables in my database.

I can select the entries of one table and the refered entries. In the refered table is also a table refered.

How can I load all linked tables with one query in Microsoft Entity Framework?

Tables:
Devices <=> Interfaces <=> information

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score -1):

Use Include()

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                          .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                          .ToList(); 
}
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)